# PostgreSQL Schema user permission management

Tags: postgresql

1. In PostgreSQL Database, I need to give only permission to the role for SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. I dont want to give the permission to alter the table such as change column values from NOT NULL to NULL.
2. How can I restrict this DDL access in PostgreSQL user.
3. Also I need to remove permission to delete the schema user from the PostgreSQL role.

Kindly suggest if you know.

Comment: What do you mean with "delete the schema user"? What exactly is a "schema user" in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

To grant the privileges to change the data, you need to grant precisely those you listed:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on the_table to the_user;
```

Only the owner (=creator) of a table is allowed to run DDL on it. So there is nothing to revoke.